# rails creating default child when parent doesn't have children and not showing it when parent has children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

is there any trick to create default child when a parent doesn't have children and not showing it when parent has children ? an after_create callback doesn't solve the problem by itself alone.now if user creates 3 children and you call "parent.children" the result not only contains those 3 children, but also the auto-created one.

**UPDATE:** I need the auto-created child only when there are no other children and when there are, I don't want the auto-created one to be among the result of "parent.children"

**Example:**
i have a product model having many variants.a customer can order a variant and so we need a variant. but sometimes the admin don't want to add variant and thinks that a product without variant it enough.so we need a default variant to let customers to order.maybe 2 month later, the admin comes and add a variant and from this time, we don't want a default one anymore. i was looking for a nice and clean solution for this problem

Comment: please post the method yu currently use to create the child...

Comment: there is no special method! just a simple association.

Comment: @Pooya It seems like several people are having difficulty understanding your problem. Can you explain why you need a default child record? Does that default child record need to be persisted in the database, or can it be instantiated as needed?

Comment: i have a product model having many variants.a customer can order a variant and so we need a variant. but sometimes the admin don't want to add variant and thinks that a product without variant it enough.so we need a default variant to let customers to order.maybe 2 month later, the admin comes and add a variant and from this time, we don't want a default one anymore. i was looking for a nice and clean solution for this problem.

Comment: Does the auto_Created child need to exist in the database? or can it be created dynamically on the fly? If it needs to be saved in the db., you are going to have to do something like set a field in the child like is default? or is_auto_created?.  and then in your controller, you need to remove any nodes with default, or auto_created set before you add the new child, Probably wrapping it in a transaction.  If it can be dynamically created, you could just rescue on the nil and build it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`after_create` should work just fine, assuming you associated any children before saving the parent:

```
class ParentModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_models
  after_create :ensure_child_exists

  def ensure_child_exists
    child_models.create(default: true) unless child_models.exists?
  end
end
```

If you then need to remove this child if new ones are added at some later point, you'll need to have a 'default' flag on the child to identify for removal, then add a callback to trigger the default child removal.

```
class ChildModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :default
  belongs_to :parent
  after_create :remove_default_if_unneeded

  scope :default, -> { where(default: true) }

  def remove_default_if_unneeded
    parent.child_models.default.destroy_all unless self.default?
  end
end
```

Comment: you didn't get the problem. now if user create 3 children and you call "parent.children" the result not only contains those 3 children, but also the auto-created one.

Comment: @Pooya: The auto-created one won't have been auto-created if other children were assigned before the parent is saved for the first time.  Or did you mean, that you want to delete the auto-created child if at some later point children are added?  Updated to show how you might do this.

Comment: I looked at your edit, and yeah, this is a solution and i had thought of but just preferred to do a kind of brain storming and see if there are any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just call a method like this in the `after_create` callback.

```
def create_child_if_needed
  Child.create(:parent_id => self.id) unless self.children.any?
end
```

This will only create the Child object if there isnt any child in the children association.

Comment: you didn't get the problem. now if user create 3 children and you call "parent.children" the result not only contains those 3 children, but also the auto-created one.